# Header and footer and nested views in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

While implementing an app in angular. I have some pages having common header and footer and different nested View. Header and footer will have have nested body views.
However, the information displayed in the header and footer will be affected by change in the nested body views.

I've found blogs regarding nested views. However, haven't noticed something regarding the use case I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Nested views inherit the scope of their parent view, so it is easy to have the parent views update according to the content of their child views / scopes.